# Adblock Plus removing text below unanswered questions

Tags: bug, status-declined, addon

I understand the reason for the massively negative feedback to this question. It's not a Stack Exchange bug, I agree. I don't care about the bug, I just wanted to draw attention to it. I thought SE would be a more pleasant place to be if a little workaround was implemented. I thought the SE community enjoyed improving the site in tiny little ways like this...

The issue is that I use FireFox with Adblock Plus and it makes the text appearing below every unanswered question in stackoverflow.com look like this

> Know someone who can answer? Share a link to this question via email, , , or .

instead of like this

> Know someone who can answer? Share a link to this question via email, Google+, Twitter, or Facebook.

Maybe it's possible to detect whether browsers use ad blockers, and change the display accordingly?

Comment: How is this an SE bug? It's your add-on that's messing up the page, file a bug with them.

Comment: Why should a web site support a user base that is actively undermining their business model - especially when there is such an iron-clad policy of  non-intrusiveness as there is on Stack Overflow, and continued participation removes almost all ads?

Answer (score 11):

This is a problem with your Adblock settings and whatever filter set you are using. It is not a problem with the SE website, nor is it a website's job to work around bugs in such addons.

If anything, you should file a bug report with Adblock (or your filter set provider) so they can fix the false positive detection.

In the mean time, remember those ads you are blocking support SE and help enable them to keep bringing this service to you. Last I checked you and I were no paying into the system any other way. They are already kind enough to drop the ads for all users over a certain low rep threshold so folks who contribute content to the system are not targeted for ads ad all!

Answer (score 10):

Or you could just... you know, not use Adblock on SE sites.

You realize that you're kind of incredibly selfish to block ads on a site that goes leaps and bounds to only show you good, relevant ads, and that you're getting this wealth of information for free? I mean, really, there's even community ad posts that let you decide what ads show up, and you can even tell SE to never show a specific ad again.

> Maybe it's possible to detect whether browsers use adblock, and change the display accordingly?

***NO***, we're not going to make the experience *better* for people who actively rob us of pretty much the only way that SE sites make income. Again, you realize that you can't make a network like Stack Exchange for free?

`</rant>`

Comment: To be fair, we also get revenue from our [Careers service](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/).